# ZeroMQ rrclient-broker not working

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to run the Python and Node.JS examples from https://github.com/imatix/zguide for the client-broker-worker architecture (rrclient, rrworker, rrbroker).

I can confirm that the Python implementation works fine, and the Node.JS implementation works fine, but when I try to combine the Node.JS rrclient with the Python rrbroker, the whole thing crashes and I get the following error:

Python quit unexpectedly while using the libzmq.3.dylib plug-in.

And the broker has the following error:
Assertion failed: (prefetched_msg.flags () & msg_t::identity) == 0 (router.cpp:276)
Abort trap: 6

Seems like Node.JS has issues connecting to Python. This seems to also come up with the basic REQ/REP architecture as well, not just client-broker-worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like re-installing pyzmq seems to fix the problem...

```
sudo pip uninstall pyzmq
sudo pip install pyzmq
```

Whew, cheers!